# wordpress admin ajax trash_comment

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, comments

I'm trying to add a trash_reason when someone delete a comment from the wp admin. I managed to add a thickbox with a dropbown listing deletion reasons and passing / updating the value of selected option in the query_string of the trashing link, but I can't get it in my add_action

Here is my code :

```
add_filter('comment_row_actions', 'filter_comments_actions', 1, 2);
function filter_comments_actions($actions, $comment)
{
global $wpdb;


$del_nonce = esc_html('_wpnonce=' . wp_create_nonce("delete-comment_$comment->comment_ID"));
$trash_url = $trash_url = esc_url("comment.php?action=trashcomment&p=$comment->comment_post_ID&c=$comment->comment_ID&$del_nonce&reason=1");
add_thickbox();
$reasons = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_jb_rejected_review_reasons');
$actions['trash'] = "
    <a href='#TB_inline?&width=400&height=200&inlineId=comment-actions-id' class='thickbox'>Trash</a> 
    <div id='comment-actions-id' style='display: none;'>
        <h3>
            Reason for deletion
        </h3>
        <form action=''>
            <select onchange='update_moderate_reason_id($comment->comment_ID)' name='rejected_reason' id='rejected_reason_$comment->comment_ID'>
        ";
foreach ($reasons as $reason) {
    $actions['trash'] .= "<option value='$reason->id'>$reason->reason</option>";
}
$actions['trash'] .= "
            </select>
            <br/>";
$actions['trash'] .= "<a onclick='log_moderation_href(this)' href='$trash_url' data-wp-lists='delete:the-comment-list:comment-$comment->comment_ID::trash=1' class='delete vim-d vim-destructive confirm-deletion-comment-$comment->comment_ID' aria-label='" . esc_attr__('Move this comment to the Trash') . "'>" . _x('Trash', 'verb') . '</a>';
$actions['trash'] .=
    "
        </form>  
    </div>
    ";
unset($actions['edit']);
return $actions; 
}


add_action('trash_comment', 'log_trash_comment', 1);

function log_trash_comment($comment_id)
{
    $reason = $_REQUEST['reason'];
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_rejected_reviews (moderator_id, 
comment_id, reason_id) VALUES (".get_current_user_id().", $comment_id, 
$reason)");
}
```

And my javascript :

```
function update_moderate_reason_id(comment_id) {

var reason_id = jQuery("select[name='rejected_reason']#rejected_reason_"+comment_id).val();
console.log(reason_id);
var confirm_link = jQuery("a.confirm-deletion-comment-"+comment_id);
var _href = confirm_link.attr('href');
if(_href.indexOf('&reason=') != -1){
    _href = _href.substr(0, _href.length-9);
}
_href += "&reason="+reason_id;
confirm_link.attr('href', _href); }

function log_moderation_href(link){
    console.log(link);
}
```

But when i var_dump() $_REQUEST in my log_trash_comment function, the reason does not appear

Thanks in advance for your precious help,

Comment: it does look alright, maybe console.log the final href also

Comment: Hi, I just did that and the href is alright  : "comment.php?action=trashcomment&p=86035&c=4&_wpnonce=0fb8114f8b&reason=6"

Comment: longshot but maybe you need `add_action('trash_comment', 'log_trash_comment', 10, 1);`

Comment: Hey, just tried it but no more success. What is really weird is that when I debug my code at the moment it enters my custom function, there is not $_GET, only $_POST with the ajax parameters for Wordpress.

Comment: Can you post your javascript for `jb_trash_comment()`? That's the only piece I'm missing in order to debug this.

Comment: missing `$_GET`? now that *is* truly strange. maybe you have an over-zealous security plugin active?

Comment: Hi, @MikeNGarrett , this js function simply console.log the <a> element. I've updated my code to help you see things clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're adding parameters to the url isn't working. The ajax request is designed to prevent parameter insertion like this.

I recommend you kick off another ajax request to handle this process rather than trying to hook into the existing process in this way.

For example, you can kick off your modal window after a comment is trashed and control the submission and logging process separately.

Comment: Hello, this is what I ended up doing. I modified the function triggered by `onclick=""` on the link to do the insert in database while not preventing the wordpress action hook trash_comment. Thanks a lot for your help !